# Monotonicity and Convexity of Stochastic Matrices

Tags: probability, matrices, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

The definition of stochastic monotonicity and convexity is given by "Stochastic Orders and Their Applications" by Moshe Shaked and George Shanthikumar (1994) as:

Let $P = \{p_{i,j} \}$ be a stochastic matrix on $\mathbb{N}_+$. Then P is said to be

1) Stochastically monotone if $\sum_{j=k}^\infty p_{i,j} \leq \sum_{j=k}^\infty p_{(i+1),j}$ for any $i$ and $k$ in $\mathbb{N}_+$;

2) Stochastically monotone convex $\sum_{j=k}^\infty p_{i,j} \leq \sum_{j=k+1}^\infty p_{(i+1),j}$ for any $i$ and $k$ in $\mathbb{N}_+$;

That is, the row vectors of the matrix are stochastically increasing. Many results follow from this definition. For example, one can show stochastic ordering between two transition matrices of discrete-time Markov chains. This in turn, implies that their respective steady-state probability distributions are ordered. I want to show that similar properties hold for the steady-state probabilities in my system. However, my problem is defined slightly differently.

Let $Q = \{q_{i,j} \}$ be my stochastic matrix on $\mathbb{N}_+$. In my system, the following relations hold:

1) $\sum_{j=k}^\infty q_{i,j} \geq \sum_{j=k}^\infty q_{(i+1),j}$ for any $i$ and $k$ in $\mathbb{N}_+$;

2) $\sum_{j=k}^\infty q_{i,j} \geq \sum_{j=k+1}^\infty q_{(i+1),j}$ for any $i$ and $k$ in $\mathbb{N}_+$;

Note that the $\leq$ sign in the original definition is replaced by a $\geq$ sign in my system. 
I have tried redefining the underlying state space, using a coupling argument, and tried to find a bounding matrix that satisfies stochastic monotonicity and convexity but also has the same steady-state distribution as the one induced by Q, all to no avail. If anybody has any ideas and/or could provide me with some help in this matter it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You should give the full reference, not only author names!

Comment: Sorry, the full reference is the book "Stochastic Orders and Their Applications" by Moshe Shaked and George Shanthikumar.

Comment: Thats good, but it is better if you edit your question to put that ninformation there!

Answer (score 0):

If some $Q$ satisfies your property (1) then $Q^2$ is stochastically monotone.

Comment: Thank you, I want to show that the steady-state probabilities are ordered. How does the fact that $Q^2$ satisfies the properties help with proving this? Also, $Q^2$ is not a stochastic matrix anymore as the rows do not necessarily sum to 1.

Comment: The stationary distribution of $Q$ is also stationary for $Q^2$. // "Also, $Q^2$ is not a stochastic matrix anymore" Whaaat? Somebody needs to reread their notes, I believe.

Comment: Yeah, sorry you are entirely correct, thank you very much. Do you have any ideas with respect to stochastically convex?

Comment: 1. Do you know how to prove the implication in my answer? 2. How come you meet both conditions in "your system"?

Comment: 1) I believe so. Since a steady-state probability distribution exists for transition matrix $Q$, $\pi Q = \pi$. As a result, $\pi Q^2 = (\pi Q) Q = \pi Q = \pi$. Thus, $Q^2$ satisfies my first property and induces the same steady-state probability distribution as $Q$.  2) Numerical testing of my system indicates that $\mathbb{E}[g(Y(S))]$ is monotone decreasing and convex in $S$ where $g(\cdot)$ is a decreasing convex function and $Y(S)$ is the random variable associated with the steady-state distribution. I wanted to prove this point but a brute-force approach is too complicated.